# Two wagmi's usePrepareContractWrite( ) in a single React functional component

Tags: javascript, react, wagmi, nextjs

There are **two different functions** in my smart contract which I want to connect to **two separate buttons** on my user interface. The component is function-based. So according to **wagmi's** documentation, I need to do as follows:

- propagate my **usePrepareContractWrite** with my arbitrary values
- pass the produced **{ config }** to the **useContractWrite(config)**
- Then { **data**, **write** }  will be produced and the transaction will be executed by calling `write`

The above order is straightforward, but what we should do when we want to do this structure twice on a single component? As obvious, we must have another set of **{ config }** and **{ **data**, **write** }**, but how should we define the names of the new variables since there are already variables with the same names?

I tried to name the new variables as something like `config2`, `data2`, or `write2` ... but that did not help. I guess I should stay with already specified names for destructing **usePrepareContractWrite** and **useContractWrite()**

Could anyone suggest a helpful idea about how I can use the second usePrepareContractWrite on the same component ( next.js page )?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many **usePrepareContractWrite()** and **useContractWrite()** hooks as you need within a NextJS component while destructuring to renamed fields.

You can change the names of destructured object fields by using a colon **(:)**

There is a good read that describes it [Rename & Destructure Variables in ES6](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming)

You could have something like that:

```js
import {usePrepareContractWrite, useContractWrite } from "wagmi";

...

// Prepare contract configurations
const { config: myConfig1 } = usePrepareContractWrite({address: contractAddress1, abi: contractAbi1, functionName: 'func1' });
const { config: myConfig2 } = usePrepareContractWrite({address: contractAddress2, abi: contractAbi2, functionName: 'func2' });

// Hook contract functions
const { data: data1, write: myFunction1 } = useContractWrite(myConfig1);
const { data: data2, write: myFunction2 } = useContractWrite(myConfig2);

...

// call contract functions
myFunction1();
myFunction2();
```

Comment: Initializing the project with Typescript is required in this case or not?

Comment: No, that’s JavaScript syntax

Comment: Yes. You are right! It works

Comment: When I am calling myFunction1() it show typeError myFunction1() is not a function I am working on ReactJs

Answer (score -2):

**There is a major difference between object and array destructuring.**

We can assign any names to our variables while destructuring arrays. In contrast, we need to stick to the already defined variable names when we want to destructure an object.

So regarding this question, by looking at Wagmi's documentation we can simply conclude that `usePrepareContractWrite( )` and `useContractWrite( )` **are simple examples of object destructuring, not array destructuring.**

As a result, we cannot use something like `config2, data2, or write2`.

However, the recommended solution to this situation is creating separate components and moving functions ( which were in the same component ) into new components. Then we can import them into the target page's return statement. Also, We may want to provide any necessary data by props for those child components from the mother component.

Comment: That's incorrect. See my answer for an explanation.